# Bootstrap error using Spring framework/maven

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, maven, jsp, frontend

Hello it's my first time using bootstrap and I'm having trouble getting it right.

This is my jsp

```html
<%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: reaganyuan
  Date: 1/6/18
  Time: 3:09 PM
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img alt="Brand" src="...">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>$$
    </nav>



<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

(Sorry cannot add images to my posts yet)
[This is my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJcRB.png) 
This is my output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU77w.png)

Comment: Tag `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/` is not closed

Comment: ah, sorry I closed it now and it still does not work;same error

Comment: You need to provide more detail. The configuration you have used like view resolution strategy and the controller request handler code which is invoked first time.

Comment: Can you also see that `font-awsome` file is loading or not? Check in browser console.